# Combining a closed inequality with an open one

Tags: inequality

Consider these two inequalities:

$$f'(x) -1> 0  \tag{1}$$

$$ 3x^2 \geq 0 \tag{2}$$

Can I use these two to say:

$$ f'(x) - 1 + 3x^2 > 0 $$

Is it correct to combine inequalities in this way? If not, where is the mistake?

(I am looking for an explanation of the mathematical step in words)

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Ok, but how would I justify doing this step in words?

Comment: Yes, of course. If $a\geq0$ and $b\geq0$ so $a+b\geq0$.

Comment: The thing that I am concerned is that one is greater or equal,  other is just greater than inequality

Answer (score 1):

This way of combining inequalities is completely fine. To understand why, suppose we have $a > 0$ and $b \ge 0$.

Observation 1: If $x > y$, then $x + z > y + z$. This can be shown formally, but intuitively, $x > y$ means that $x$ is "above" $y$ if you visualize the real numbers as a vertical line where larger numbers are higher up. Now, adding $z$ to a number moves it up a certain distance, but since $x+z$ and $y+z$ both add $z$, we move both numbers up by the same amount, so their ordering remains the same.

Observation 2: If $x > y$ and $y \ge z$, then $x > z$. Using the visualisation above, $x$ is above $y$ and $y$ is either the same as $z$ or above $z$. In either case, $x$ is above $z$.

Combining these two observations, we have: $a + b > 0 + b = b$, and since $b \ge 0$, $a + b > 0$.

Comment: You get:

$$f'(x) - 1 > 0$$

And then,

$$ f'(x) -1 + 3x^2 > 3x^2 $$

And since $ 3x^2 \geq 0 $$

Comment: $ f'(x) -1 + 3x^2 > 3x^2 \geq 0 $

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to conclude at:

$ f' -1 + 3x^2 > 0 $ from the above

Comment: Pick $a := f'(x)-1$ and $b := 3x^2$. Does that clear up things?